# .NET 4 framework performance decrease

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I am very surprised by results of my .net frameworks performance tests. Look at the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (long len = 8000000; len <= 16000000; len += 2000000)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {

            long sum = 0;
            for (int x = 1; x <= len; x++)
            {
                sum += x;
            }

        }
    }
    s1.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(s1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

When I target .net 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 frameworks and x64 platform the result is about **520 ms**. When I target .net 4.0, 4.5, 4.6 frameworks and x64 platform the result is about **1230 ms**. When targeting x86 platform result is about 1560 ms for all the frameworks. My PC is x64 based. The question is why is where such a big difference between .net frameworks under 4th and above?
All the examples were built with vs2015, under release mode, with the default build options.

Comment: Have you tried profiling each of the configurations?

Comment: Ideally, a smart enough optimizer would eliminate the loops entirely and just start and stop a stopwatch. What the point of *such* an artificial benchmark?

Comment: Sadly, Eric Lipperts great articles on benchmarking mistakes are no longer directly available, but you can still get them through the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150402042603/http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one). -- maybe you've fallen into one of the many pits of benchmarking.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I took this benchmark from [Algorithms in a Nutshell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516246.do) where author compares Java, C and Python performance. But question is about .net 4 framework performance, everywhere it is written, the performance of .net 4 should be better than 3.5 etc.

Comment: @Corak Thank for the link. I think that I'm doing everything correctly. Choosed metric is average execution time, I run compiled program (not from debugger), compile in release, not debug mode, I use _stopwatch_, not the _DateTime.Now_

Comment: @andc - There are times where people have to make trade-offs. Imagine if the developers have a choice in how to implement X. If they implement it one way, they make pointless loops insanely fast but slow down most real world code. If they implement it the other way, real world code is fast but pointless loops are more slow. Which way would you *want* them to implement it?

Comment: I'm getting very different timings.  You are using the new .NET 4.6 jitter (aka RyuJIT) when you target any 4.x framework.  It is not exactly "better", the was rewritten to fix several hard-to-fix bugs in the legacy x64 jitter.  One particular bug probably matters here, its optimizer did not have bounded execution time and could take far too long on a big method body.  The difference in this *particular* code is that it fails to remove the  useless`sum += x;` statement.  The legacy x64 jitter removes it and the x86 jitter removes it, the latter is bogged down by *long*.